# NG X - Many components displayed will lag browser on-navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Let's say I've created a component that takes a JSON object that has an array of a random number of strings. This component needs to be repeated X number of times (can be between 1,000 and 10,000). It seems that navigating to the route that contains this insanely large list of components lags the browser immensely and I was wondering how to deal with this. I've created a sample stackblitz that will show-case this render lag. Notice how long it takes to actually navigate between `Dash` and `Mess`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddl9hj

In a real-world application, let's assume the amount of "lines" that need to be rendered by each `message` component are random and the approximate size in pixels is not known.

Comment: https://medium.com/@zainzafar/how-to-use-virtual-scrolling-using-angular-7-cdk-9802110111fa

Comment: Yes I would love to use that but they only have "fixed size" virtual scrolling right now.

Comment: You can implement your own unlimited scroll with buffer.

Comment: Is there an easier way, say delaying the render until the containing component has been rendered?

Comment: You can probably split the array into chunks and a delay in between when emitting it to stream